# 16.04 - LibreOffice Writer 5.4.0.3 hangs while opening signed .odt files

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice

When I open a signed .odt document the app hangs, like this:
[image: LO Writer hang]

---

Running

```
libreoffice <filename>.odt
```

produces no stdout: no error messages, nothing...

---

Tried signing with OpenPGP and X.509 certificate - same result.

---

**Specs:**
**From Writer**
Version: 5.4.0.3
Build ID: 1:5.4.0~rc3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1
CPU threads: 4; OS: Linux 4.10; UI render: default; VCL: gtk2; 
Locale: sl-SI (en_US.UTF-8); 
Calc: group
**Graphics**
GPU: nVidia 450 GTS
Driver: xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-16.04 (1:1.0.14-0ubuntu1~16.04.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling MUFFIN solved this problem